# MATLAB: How to find area of an arbitrary surface in a 2d closed shape

Tags: matlab, area, surface

I have a closed 2d surface as below:

```
r=1+0.1*sin(5*theta)+a*sin(6*theta);
x=r.*cos(theta);
y=r.*sin(theta);
plot(x,y);
```

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to find its area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From MATLAB documentation:** http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyarea.html

---

You can use `polyarea`

**Sintax**

```
A = polyarea(X,Y)
A = polyarea(X,Y,dim)
```

**Description**

`A = polyarea(X,Y)` returns the area of the polygon specified by the vertices in the vectors `X` and `Y`.

If `X` and `Y` are matrices of the same size, then polyarea returns the area of polygons defined by the columns `X` and `Y`.

If `X` and `Y` are multidimensional arrays, polyarea returns the area of the polygons in the first nonsingleton dimension of `X` and `Y`.

`A = polyarea(X,Y,dim)` operates along the dimension specified by scalar dim.

**Example**

```
L = linspace(0,2.*pi,9);
xv = 1.2*cos(L)';
yv = 1.2*sin(L)';

xv = [xv ; xv(1)];
yv = [yv ; yv(1)];

A = polyarea(xv,yv)

// Result A = 4.0729
```

---

```
plot(xv,yv);
title(['Area = ' num2str(A)])
axis image
```

[image]

Comment: It's preferable that you provide an example that is relevant to the OP's question rather than literally copy/pasting the MATLAB documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it and it worked, but actually I think there was no need for 
xv = [xv ; xv(1)];
yv = [yv ; yv(1)];

Thanks

Comment: @Suever It might help, it isn't?

Comment: @arglab It is far better to *link* to their documentation and show the usage using data similar to the original question. A complete duplication of the documentation is not helpful.

Comment: @arglab Could you please give one +1 to my question if you think it was worth asking, since I am about to get blocked because my questions were poorly received (did not get +1 points) thanks in advance

Comment: @Soheilsmz Done :) have a nice day